# How to force a view to keep focus?

Tags: java, android, button, view, focus

I have a view named `choice_view` that is made visible whenever a specific button is pushed. The view contains multiple buttons for choices.

My issue is that the new view only takes up a small portion of the screen and the rest of my UI buttons are still visible and more problematically you can still activate those other buttons while `choice_view` is showing.

I would like to make only the buttons within the `choice_view` touchable, and the rest of the buttons that are on the screen not touchable while the `choice_view` is visible.

I *could* add in code to all of the other touchable buttons, but there are so many of them, that I was hoping It was possible to accomplish this using code in the `onClick` method when I set `choice_view` to visible.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable them I'd say you could iterate through root layout' children, disabling all buttons and skipping the ones inside choice_view. Or if all you want is to not take any action when one of them is clicked you could have all of your buttons targeting the same handler, have two different switch(case) to handle the buttons that are in and out of your layout, that way you could prevent the whole switch from being triggered while choice_view is visible.